# Should something be done about the current duplicate statuses of these related questions on readied actions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, questions, specific-question, duplicates

The three following questions currently exist (ordered from newest to oldest):

1. [If I Ready an action, can I then use my reaction for something else?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/159983)
2. [Reaction while holding a readied action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150533)
3. [Can you forgo your readied action to take an opportunity attack instead?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123481)

They are all extremely similar, and in fact, the second question is currently marked as a duplicate of the third. However, at least to me, it is quite clear that the first question is a duplicate of the second.

Note that the first question has one well-received answer, while the second question currently has no answers whatsoever, and the third has one very well-received answer.

**What should be done about these three questions?** Should the second question have its duplicate target changed to the first question? Should the first question be marked as a duplicate of the third? Something else?

I think my biggest confusion in from the logical inconsistency. If question 1 is a duplicate of question 2, and question 2 is a duplicate of question 3, isn't question 1 a duplicate of question 3? Which part of this is incorrect?

Comment: Related: [If an answer to question A can be found in question B, should we close A as duplicate of B?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7523/if-an-answer-to-question-a-can-be-found-in-question-b-should-we-close-a-as-dupl)

Answer (score 5):

## Close #3 as a duplicate of #1, and fix the dupe target of #2

It looks like #1 and #2 are identical to each other, and one of them should indeed be marked as a duplicate of the other (as you note).

However, the two questions are not quite the same as #3, which is a more specific subset of the other two; whereas #1 and #2 present the general question of taking *any reaction* instead of the readied action, #3 specifically asks about taking an *opportunity attack* instead of the readied action. (#2 does use opportunity attacks as an *example*, but it is not the primary question.)

Since #3 is a subset of #1 and #2, we should look at [doppelgreener's answer to the relevant meta, "If an answer to question A can be found in question B, should we close A as duplicate of B?"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7524/33569):

> We close Question A as a duplicate of Question B only when **all** of the following is true:
>
> - It's the same question, or Question A is already covered **obviously** as a subset of Question B. Obvious here means I can tell at a glance it's there.
> - Question B has an **obvious** answer to Question A. Obvious here means I get a straightforward answer without hard searching — a couple of sentences buried in the middle of a post, or an answer which only sort of implies an answer to Question A, doesn't count as obvious.
> - There is not some strong compelling reason to covering Question A alone, separately from Question B. (If the above bullet points are met this rarely happens.)

In this case, it seems like #3 should be closed as a dupe of #1 (despite #1 being newer), since #3 is fully and obviously a subset of #1; opportunity attacks are just one type of reaction, and there's no compelling reason to cover them separately.

(#2 is not the preferred dupe target since, as it was already incorrectly closed as a duplicate of #3, it has no answers. As mentioned above, #2's primary question covers the general case that #1 does, but uses the primary question in #3 merely as an example.)

Comment: Do you think that marking #3 as a duplicate will lower the visibility of the answer already there? (At the very least, any future duplicate would link only to #1 and not to #3 at all)

Comment: @Medix2: I think it would, by definition - though questions can have multiple dupe targets, so relevant questions could include both #1 and #3 in the list of links to duplicates. I'd merge them, except kviiri's answer to #3 makes some points that are only relevant to that question (and not to the example given in #1) so it might be better to post it as a new answer on #1 instead if needed...

Comment: #1 is different as it refers to casting a spell as a reaction. I think this is an important point of clarity that should be reflected by changing the question itself.  Using a reaction to cast a spell is much different from using a reaction to make an opportunity attack.  I was previously confused about casting multiple spells per turn thinking it was you can't cast multiple spells per round.

Comment: @Kieveli: It seems to be like both #1 and #2 are asking about the general case, and merely using different examples to illustrate that case (casting *feather fall* and making an opportunity attack respectively). But I could be wrong there.