# Is this question about the Magic Initiate feat a duplicate that should be closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

Candidate for closure: [Can an Arcane Trickster or Eldritch Knight with the Magic Initiate feat (picking the wizard list) use spell slots to cast the chosen 1st-level spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/176665/62294)

Dupe Target: [Can you cast a spell learned from the Magic Initiate feat using spell slots?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68451/can-you-cast-a-spell-learned-from-the-magic-initiate-feat-using-spell-slots?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Is this question asking specifically about an Arcane Trickster or Eldritch Knight a duplicate of the more general question which does not specify any class or subclass?

Comment: Circumstances surrounding this question are being discussed here: [What do we do when a question is covered as a subset of another, but the answers are insufficient for answering the special case?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11255)

Answer (score 6):

## It is a duplicate that should be closed.

**Question A**: [Can an Arcane Trickster or Eldritch Knight with the Magic Initiate feat (picking the wizard list) use spell slots to cast the chosen 1st-level spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/176665/62294)

**Question B**: [Can you cast a spell learned from the Magic Initiate feat using spell slots?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68451/can-you-cast-a-spell-learned-from-the-magic-initiate-feat-using-spell-slots?noredirect=1&lq=1)

We will examine these questions according to the [three duplicate criteria](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7523/if-an-answer-to-question-a-can-be-found-in-question-b-should-we-close-a-as-dupl/7524#7524)

### Criterion 1:

> *It's the same question, or Question A is already covered obviously as a subset of Question B. Obvious here means I can tell at a glance it's there.*

In this case, **Question B**, the general case, does not specify any class or subclass. Naturally, the scope of the question then includes all classes and subclasses, thereby covering **Question A** in its scope. One might object, "it isn't obvious that Arcane Trickster or Eldritch Knight are covered by **Question B**." It's not obvious that *any particular* class or subclass or subclass are covered by it because it *is* obvious that the question concerns any and all classes and subclasses having spell slots.

### Criterion 2:

> *Question B has an obvious answer to Question A. Obvious here means I get a straightforward answer without hard searching — a couple of sentences buried in the middle of a post, or an answer which only sort of implies an answer to Question A, doesn't count as obvious.*

**Question B** has an [obvious answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/176679/62294) to **Question A**. Half of this answer is dedicated to dealing with the special case of **Question A** and is clearly sign posted with a header.

### Criterion 3:

> *There is not some strong compelling reason to covering Question A alone, separately from Question B. (If the above bullet points are met this rarely happens.)*

There is now no reason to leave **Question A** open. When **Question A** was originally asked, **Criterion 2** was not satisfied, but it has since been satisfied in the linked answer.