# Are any of these dnd-5e questions about spells and their target becoming invalid duplicates?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

We have quite a few questions about spell effects and what happens when their target enters a state where they could not have been targeted by the spell in the first place:

1. [Can Polymorph end spells that require the target to be humanoid?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103845)
2. [Is a spell suppressed or removed when the target temporarily becomes invalid?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/133379) [1]
3. [Does the light from Branding Smite persist after the target dies?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/182265) [7]
4. [What happens if modifications are made to the base entity while it is under the effects of a suppressed True Polymorph?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/157644)
5. [Is it possible to possess a non-humanoid creature with a combination of True Polymorph and Magic Jar?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/131210)
6. [If a creature was flying via the Fly spell and dies, does it continue flying?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/162649)
7. [Would the Animate Objects spell end an ongoing spell affecting the targeted object(s)?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/158606)
8. [Does a Huge Object that has already been Animated continue to be Animated if it is Enlarged to Gargantuan?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/133305)
9. [Can a willing creature targeted by the Animal Shapes spell choose to return to their normal form before the spell as a whole ends?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/169076)
10. [What happens if polymorph ends while under disguise self?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/180643) [2]

A bracketed number indicates that the question has been closed as a duplicate of a question in this list. For example, question 2 has been closed as a duplicate of question 1. Note, I made all of these closures and they are, effectively, what brought me to ask this question.

Notably, the very last question is closed as a duplicate of the second. Is this correct? Is that the *only* one that should be closed or are there others as well?

Note: I left out a few related questions that are, to me, clearly *not* duplicates despite asking about similar topics because they hinge directly and explicitly on a spell's specific wording. For example:

- [After Tiny Hut has been cast, does the dome disappear when a large creature appears in it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177601)
- [If one of the platinum rings that serves as a component of the Warding Bond spell is removed and then replaced, do the effects of the spell resume?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/169068)

Comment: Related: [If an answer to question A can be found in question B, should we close A as duplicate of B?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7523/60913)