# Can we Reopen "What happens if you cast Counterspell on a creature that is not casting a spell?"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

I do not think that [What happens if you cast Counterspell on a creature that is not casting a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115246/what-happens-if-you-cast-counterspell-on-a-creature-that-is-not-casting-a-spell) is a duplicate of [What happens when a caster targets an object that looks like a creature with a spell that targets only creatures?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96327/what-happens-when-a-caster-targets-an-object-that-looks-like-a-creature-with-a-s). In fact, besides the fact that they both deal with targeting, the question is not at all the same.

My understanding is that we only mark as duplicate when the questions are the same, and not because the answers could overlap.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Similar meta discussion(s): [Non-duplicate question with answer in another question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5019/non-duplicate-question-with-answer-in-another-question), [If an answer to question A can be found in question B, should we close A as duplicate of B?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7523/if-an-answer-to-question-a-can-be-found-in-question-b-should-we-close-a-as-dupl)

Answer (score 4):

They're completely different questions.

Reopened.

You're correct in your understanding. We close questions as duplicates only when they're genuinely the same question and the answers in the target obviously answer the supposed duplicate. (Usually those are one and the same.)

That's not the case here. It looks like these questions could possibly touch on the same concepts, if I'm reading correctly, but that doesn't make for a duplicate.